# Modifying a Visual Studio Basic Program from Another Solution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Title. Basically, I'd like to be able to make a simple VB solution, and then have a DIFFERENT solution be able to modify some aspect of that solution, from font family (say, font A without this mod, and font B with it), to actually extending code to allow for something the original does not. Help?

Comment: Are you asking how to programmically modify an `sln` file? If so, I believe its just XML. Use something like [XMLDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure - I'm rather new to this. To be more specific, a friend of mine is making a program in Visual Studio, in Visual Basic, and I want to see if I can make an add-on solution, kind of, that would be able to change the font throughout the program if the user has both the original program and my add-on downloaded.

Comment: Do you mean the font of the IDE? Because this is not stored in the solution file. It's a setting in Visual Studio, most likely stored in the registry or in a config file.

Comment: No, the font of the forms in the original solution, executable, whatever